kmm data classes on swift: "init() is unavailable"
I have a kmm app, I use Firebase Firestore for this.
On shared code "commonMain" (Kotlin), I have this class:
@Serializable
data class GeoPoint(
    var latitude: Double = 0.0,
    var longitude: Double = 0.0
)

I am trying to instantiate a simple object in my iOS (Swift) code:
@State var myGeopoint = GeoPoint()

However this returns the error: 'init()' is unavailable
For a list of GeoPoints the error does not appear.
Why this is different?
Any easier workaround? This should be related to Kotlin more than with Swift I believe.

Default parameters do not carry over from Kotlin to Swift. You'll need to explicitly provide the values.
You can add default parameters to KMP output using SKIE. However, because of the implementation, it is suggested that you do so as needed rather than turning the feature on for your full API.
The additional, mandatory disclaimer that this isn't just Objective-C preventing default params. As the implementation of SKIE demonstrated (we made SKIE), the semantics of Kotlin and Swift default params are quite different. The implications of that, and the implementation to support them, is why they're not on by default.
But I digress.
